# Move cursor position in textarea to start position after setting value

Tags: javascript, html, dom, range, textarea

### HTML:

```
<textarea id="text-box" size="20"></textarea>
<button onclick="selectText()">Get Content</button>
```

### JavaScript:

```
function selectText() {
  var txtArea = document.getElementById('text-box');
  txtArea.value = "Some Text";
  txtArea.focus();
  console.log(txtArea.value.length)

  var sel = window.getSelection();
  var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);

  console.log('range.collapsed',range.collapsed)

  range.collapse(true);
}
```

The above code indicates that the range is already collapsed, and the newly set content isn't selected.  The cursor is at the end of the content.  I want the cursor to be set to the beginning of the content.  If I set the selection to the entire content, and then try to collapse it, the following code doesn't work.

### Tried:

```
function selectText() {
  var txtArea = document.getElementById('text-box');
  txtArea.value = "Some Text";
  txtArea.focus();
  console.log(txtArea.textContent.length)

  txtArea.setSelectionRange(0, txtArea.value.length);

  var sel = window.getSelection();
  console.log(sel.rangeCount)

  sel.collapseToStart();//Doesn't work

  //Also tried the following
  //var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
  //range.collapse(true);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `setSelectionRange(0, 0)`

Comment: `txtArea.setSelectionRange(0, 0);` does work.  I'm not sure why, but I can confirm that changing the "selectionEnd" parameter to zero works.

Answer (score 0):

I try the code `sel.collapseToStart()` and its work fine. So maybe its a compatibility issues. What browser do you use?

https://codepen.io/gwtjs/pen/qzrJbp

Comment: I'm using Chrome to develop my app, and was testing in Firefox with JSFiddle.